# Is there any way to roll back the most recent update?

Tags: package-management, updates

This has happened to me many times in the last 5 years: an upgrade broke my system.
Each time I end up with this situation, I have to reinstall the whole system, which is really annoying.

Is there any way to roll back the most recent update to be able to have a functional system without reinstalling? If not, which is the best way to suggest this as a top priority idea?

I read this idea was described in brainstorm.ubuntu.com, but it feels it is dead, and the forums are full of examples of updates breaking things, that's why I feel something needs to be done about this topic.

Comment: @GatesVP This point you made 8+ yrs ago is still plaguing Ubuntu (can't speak for other distros but they're probably no better). I find this totally frustrating. Someone should have your words printed in 64 pt font and hang in front of every newbie about to plunge into the world of linux.

Comment: I have to agree that a backup image is the way to go. It is not stated if this is a 'production' system. If it is and is feasible to have a clone test system then that with image backup is the way to go. If just a app update, then the quickest solution is to downgrade with or without a 'force' option.

Answer (score 19):

In synaptics, you can at least control, what have been the recent updates: File-menu, history.

(if synaptic is startable, with the broken system). So with an apt-...-command, to revert their update, it shouldn't be too hard.

I guess there is a history-command for the command line too.

Maybe you have to delete the whole package, and install a specific version. Afaik, it is possible to install a specific version, but I never had the need to do so.

#### update: Looked up how to do with apt:

Find packages installed in the last 3x24h:

```
find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -3 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##'
```

With apt-cache policy, you see available versions of a program:

```
sudo apt-cache policy PROGRAM:
 *** 3.6.7+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.3+nobinonly-0ubuntu4 0
```

here 3.6.7 and 3.6.3 . Now you know what earlier version might be installed (often not the immediate predecessor):

```
sudo apt-get install PROGRAM=3.6.3
```

Then you need to do an apt-pinning, to prevent future updates:

Create a new file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ (if >= 10.4) named after your program,

```
Package: program
Pin: version 3.6.3*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Comment: Thanks all for the info. I can't wait for ubuntu to manage zfs out of the box!

Comment: I'm sorry - what has it to do with zfs? Does zfs manage rollbacks? Or do the updates break your zfs-install? Or does the zfs-update break something?

Comment: What if the version is `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12` according to apt? It refuses to accept that as a version number though. I want to downgrade form `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13` to `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12`

Comment: thanks, suuuuuuuuuuuuuch a pain though. my last update which utterly destroyed controller input has exactly 80 packages listed on `find /var/lib/dpkg/info/ -name \*.list -mtime -3 | sed 's#.list$##;s#.*/##' ` at this point it's less of a hassle to reinstall my entire system

Comment: You show how to list the upgraded programs, and how to downgrade a *single* program. So how do you downgrade all listed programs in one go?

Answer (score 11):

Mostly you can consult `/var/log/apt/history.log` for changes done by apt/synaptic. It's just a little forensic and alot of cut/paste to do.

Go back to the date when your system was still working fine.

First take all packages that got installed since then and put them together in an uninstall script. When the script has finished, start re-adding all removed packages again.

An example case:
logfile:

```
Start-Date: 2014-05-28  21:28:11
Commandline: synaptic
Install: libfglrx-amdxvba1:amd64 (13.12-3kali1, automatic), libgl1-fglrx-glx:amd64 (13.12-3kali1), glx-alternative-fglrx:amd64 (0.4.1kali1, automatic), libfglrx:amd64 (13.12-3kali1, au$
Remove: fglrx-glx-ia32:amd64 (12-6+point-3)
End-Date: 2014-05-28  21:28:27
```

you can see,

```
libfglrx-amdxvba1:amd64 libgl1-fglrx-glx:amd64 glx-alternative-fglrx:amd64 & libfglrx:amd64
```

got installed by Synaptic. as like `libfglrx:amd64` got removed by Synaptic.

We went the reverse order, so first we remove the newly installed packages and we re-add the packages that got removed.

A working command for this case could looks like:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y libfglrx-amdxvba1:amd64 libgl1-fglrx-glx:amd64 glx-alternative-fglrx:amd64 libfglrx:amd64 && sudo apt-get install -y libfglrx:amd64
```

Maybe it wouldn't be the best idea to go without the `-y` switch - to have more control about the process (to avoid broken dependencies). Most of you wouldn't break their finger while do a few verification "y"

In most cases a rollback is possible this way, but if dependencies are already broken - you may run into a even bigger issue.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time if your system is broken it is a **kernel** problem.

Simply boot an older kernel and reinstall the most recent packages (especially kernel packages) that probably didn't update correctly.
Few notes:

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

is your friend to check what is the list of the recently updated/installed packages

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

can most of the time fix half-installed packages

Comment: How exactly do you "simply" boot an older kernel?

Comment: @DanDascalescu In GRUB there's usually the option to boot the previous kernel

Comment: Precise details. Panic mode. Broken system no internet no mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this yet.  Filesystem level snapshot/rollback is one of the features of the upcoming btrfs, but it has a ways yet to become feature complete and stable enough to use as the default filesystem.

Comment: For filesystem snapshots, you could use LVM instead, with ext3 or ext4.

Comment: @Flimm, now you can, though it does not work very well and requires that you set up LVM when you install in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a major upgrade, I clone the disk using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). Burn it on a CD, have a spare (external) HDD available and follow the instructions on the Clonezilla LiveCD. Choose the `partition-image` mode, this uses the least space.

If you think you've broken your system (or wish to revert any changes), simply boot in the Clonezilla LiveCD, select the image on your (external) HDD and restore it. As these images are a literal copy of every bit on your disk, this might take a few hours depending on your disk speed and connection speed (the connection between the data, usually an external USB HDD, and the computer).

By the way, this is called a backup method.

Answer (score 2):

You can [install an older version of a given package (downgrade) with apt or dpkg easily](https://askubuntu.com/a/34908/82061). Finding an older version of the package is the problem as these often disappear from the pool and mirrors as updates roll in.

If you install the package from an install CD or an outdated mirror or a cache, you will also need to keep it pinned to the old version so it won't be upgraded until you allow that. Which means you have to watch for updates and test them until your problem is fixed. This is of course a problem since meanwhile (maybe forever) you'll be left with the unfixed, possibly insecure package. That means every user with some kind of system issue will be left in some random state until they can resolve it.

All software also isn't forwards compatible, so an older version of something may well not behave right when fed with newer configuration or data files. Obviously this is impossible to solve unless you also roll back all user data to a state before the upgrade was done.

It would be great if there was a way to do this, but it is massively problematic. Anyone who thinks there is a coherent solution should write a proposal and invite comments or, better yet, make a proof of concept solution (code, script, document). Trolling and whining is not constructive.

Because there is no clean technical solution, most software is developed (and integrated) with "the only way is forward" mentality. Trying to manage outdated versions is a waste of everyone's time. Found problems are fixed in newer versions ASAP. As a minor solution, I would like to see an archive of previous package versions kept somewhere for the occasional temporary workaround.

Meanwhile you can report bugs and don't expect bleeding edge software to never fail. A fix, once found, should be in the next update. Devs are humans (mostly), and therefore fallible. Computers are fiddly and full of insane variety and detail. Defensively maintained systems using well-supported components and stable integrated software distribution can be very stable without becoming insecure or non-upgradeable despite this.

Comment: What the heck. You literally linked to another answer as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set up `timeshift`.

If an update breaks your system, restore the last good snapshot.

Comment: should be mandatory, ubuntu breaks everything all the time

Answer (score 1):

Type "sudo apt autoremove" through terminal and press enter key on the keyboard. It will autoremove all the redundant and unwanted library packages (and hopefully those packages that broke your system).

Then type "sudo apt autoclean" through terminal and press enter key on the keyboard. This will clean any unwanted files including those saved in the /temp directory.

Then type "sudo apt purge" through terminal and press enter key on the keyboard. This will permanently remove all the files which are not necessary.

Once done this try reinstalling the programs which you need.

Always have a current image of your system handy. Use clonezilla to keep images always handy. Its difficult situation. I am a newbie so sorry if my suggestions are bad.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

With Synaptics (Ubuntu18) you can Package->Force version...

Select version in the combo-box, if available.

Comment: how, explain more

Comment: as in I have no internet, no mouse