# Issue with a 16.04 update

Tags: launcher, autohide

I had my launcher on auto-hide, and reveal on left corner with the sensitivity set in the middle of the slider. When I wanted to see my launcher I would move the cursor to the top left corner, until I updated Ubuntu today.

Now, I have to have the sensitivity set to high and drag my cursor up the left side of the screen and into the left corner and sometimes it doesn't work.

How do I uninstall the updates that were just made?

Comment: What do you mean by updates? Are you talking about just the regular `apt` upgrades, or do you mean 18.04?

Comment: Not 18.04. The software updater wanted to update software like: security updates, libre office updates, Linux kernel, etc... based on what [Paul Benson](https://askubuntu.com/users/802479/paul-benson) said it was the kernel update that caused the problem that I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not autohide Launcher by using `left side` behaviour instead of `corner`. It's far easier to control and does the same thing. Or just hold down the superuser button for Launcher to re-appear.

The recent update was the kernel which altered my grub2 menu (amongst other things), but I was easily able to restore that to how it was before as I had a copy.

If you're talking about rolling back the kernel, it's done by quite complicated and awkward commands. There's a whole discussion on it [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353413).

There's another discussion on how to [rollback upgrades generally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34888/is-there-any-way-to-roll-back-the-most-recent-upgrade) with different suggestions, again laborious. As you can see Linux doesn't yet provide for a direct simple solution to rollback your system.

The easiest solution of all without doubt is to already have a backup of the Ubuntu system, preferably by an image. If anything goes awry with an upgrade you can restore to your previous situation in minutes. Clonezilla is your Ubuntu friend, or I use Macrium Reflect as it images my Windows system too.

Comment: I didn't know about the superuser button. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling. I will look into Clonezilla and Macrium Reflect for the future. Thank you!