# I think an update may have created a network problem on Artful ardvark. How do I delete the last update?

Tags: networking, updates

I think an update may have created a network problem on Artful ardvark. How do I delete the last update? I can't connect to a network to update any patches.

I can not connect to a wireless network. I used to be able to connect and then a few days ago it started disconnecting and reconnecting. After that it would no longer connect. I could connect to a wireless printer and print. I need solutions that don't include connecting to the internet to update or get any packages as I can't do either.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the last update until I had tried a reboot and select the next older kernel version at the GRUB menu. Does your network then work properly? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have already tried several older versions. No change. It worked just fine on Ardvark before an update. But after the update, it wouldn't work with any version.

Comment: It is difficult to impossible to roll back an update on Ubuntu, more so if you do not know what package is causing the problem. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/34888/is-there-any-way-to-roll-back-the-most-recent-upgrade

Comment: The commands were for Ubuntu 10.04 and don't work in 17.10 so it is a new question.

Comment: I can not help you without more information. Those commands should work fine in 17.10, what makes you think they do not ? You need to run them and post any error messages. I need to know what package or packages you are having problems with. If you feel your question is in some way unique you need to explain why.

Comment: Instead of rolling back an update let's focus on why it doesn't work any more.  Please follow [this  advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit] your question with the relevant info and a number of people here will be able to help you.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu doesn't have roll-back processing like other systems have. You either backup before the update and restore it if bricks or test an update on a [clone partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade). Assuming neither were done the only thing you can do now is post your current problem and seek solutions.

Comment: Ok, How do I fix the network problem then, without doing the rollback, and without being able to connect to the internet at all. I can't update or get any packages.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Instead of rolling back a bunch of packages in bulk I rather recommend that you [open a new question](/questions/ask) to [investigate the networking issue](/a/425205/175814). In the best case that will result in a solution *without roll-back*, in the worst case it should result in the knowledge *which packages* to roll back.