# How to roll back ONLY the most recent Software&Updates update [2018]

Tags: updates

I have just run and installed recommended updates using "Software & Updates" in Ubuntu 18.04.
Unfortunately, my primary work application "Houdini" now crashes on launch.
I need to roll back just this last update.
Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

A quick search only returns the following 7 year old post:

[Is there any way to roll back the most recent upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34888/is-there-any-way-to-roll-back-the-most-recent-upgrade)

OP update
So this is a list of my Updates from var/apt/history.log file
From this list, what would I need to do to roll back?

> Upgrade: libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64
>   (0.105-20,0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-compute-396:amd64(396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-compute-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   libnvidia-encode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-encode-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>   nvidia-kernel-common-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396:amd64
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-gl-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>   libnvidia-fbc1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-fbc1-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
>
> libnvidia-decode-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-decode-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   libnvidia-cfg1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-20, 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1),
>
> nvidia-utils-396:amd64
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   nvidia-dkms-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> nvidia-compute-utils-396:amd64
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) 
>   nvidia-driver-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1),
>
> libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 (0.105-20, 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1),
>
> policykit-1:amd64 (0.105-20, 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1),
>
> libnvidia-common-396:amd64
>   (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1), 
>   gir1.2-polkit-1.0:amd64 (0.105-20, 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.1), 
>   nvidia-kernel-source-396:amd64 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1,
>   396.24.10-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)

Comment: You can look at the last set of entries in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.  if it was part of a standard update that broke it, that will list all the packages that were installed during the update, including the versions.  You can sift through that to determine the latest changes, and from that determine an `apt-get install` command that would install the older versions (but I don't have such a process more detailed out then that, my apologies)

Comment: Once you have this ironed out, take a look at Timeshift https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/