# Logitech MX Master 3S Mouse scroll wheel not working after Ubuntu update

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I'm currently running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. The other day I was prompted to update my system (I'm assuming migrating from 22.04.2 to 22.04.3). Now the scroll-wheel on my mouse doesn't work.

I have a Bluetooth connected Logitech MX Master 3S mouse. After this update, the scroll wheel no longer works.

I confirmed the scroll wheel works by testing it on a laptop that runs Windows 10. It works fine on that computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to trouble-shoot?

If not, then how do you revert an update?

Thank you!

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, only mentioning Ubuntu (not which Ubuntu product, which release of that product etc).  You ask about reverting an update?  How are we to know what backup procedure you put in place (*some file-systems provide additional options; but you've not told us what file-system you're using either*)  Did you try booting with the older kernel?  Did it make a difference?  Your option maybe using an older kernel stack (*if available for your unstated product/release*) if your system just switched HWE kernel for example - but we'd be guessing not having specifics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to roll back the most recent update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34888/is-there-any-way-to-roll-back-the-most-recent-update)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that it can be fixed with Solaar. Just install the program and run it on boot so it sits in your dock. In Solaar select your MX Master 3S and turn on 'Scroll Wheel Resolution'. Another great thing that solaar fixed for me was the horizontal scroll direction by turning on Thumb Wheel Direction.